# Is there a way group listeners with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using gulp to merge many js files into one file. For each page where I need to add JS code, I create a new file to keep my code separated.

The problem with my approach is when reusing the id names in my HTML in multiple forms, the wrong event may get fired in the wrong time causing some problems.

To prevent this problem from happening, I typically start all of my selector with a wrapper in most cases the form name.

For example

```
$(function(){

    $('#create_reservation_form #type').change(function(e){
        // do stuff...
    });

    $('#create_reservation_form #brand').change(function(e){
        // do stuff...
    });

    $('#create_reservation_form #category').change(function(e){
        // do stuff...
    });

});
```

The above work perfectly except I have to repeat my wrapper id before each selector. Is there a way to ovoid having to rewriting the wrapper id each time by saying the following code should only with if it is wrapped with a giving id?

In another words, is there a way to do something like this (This below code has made up syntax so it does not work)

```
$(function(){

    $('#create_reservation_form').group(function(){

        $('#type').change(function(e){
            // do stuff...
        });

        $('#brand').change(function(e){
            // do stuff...
        });

        $('#category').change(function(e){
            // do stuff...
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: `var group = $('#create_reservation_form'); group.find('#type').change(function(e){..`

Answer (score -1):

You can delegate to the form element and chain any number of `on()` or do as @Keith suggests by storing the parent object as variable and use `find()` or delegated `on()`

```
$('#create_reservation_form')
   .on('change', '#type', function(e) {
      // do stuff...
   }).on('change', '#brand',function(e) {
      // do stuff...
   }).on('change', '#category',function(e) {
      // do stuff...
   });
```

Or for more organizational clarity :

```
$('#create_reservation_form')
   .on('change', '#type', typeChange)
   .on('change', '#brand', brandChange)
   .on('change', '#category', catChange);

// since each file will include own `$(function()` wrapper can re-use
// these function names since they will each be in own scope
function typeChange(e){
   // do stuff for type input...
}

function brandChange(e){
   // do stuff for brand input...
}

function catChange(e){
   // do stuff for category input...
}
```